# Picker itemlist and index update

Tags: c#, xamarin, picker

I'm working on my fist app with Xamarin Forms and I'm struggling with a piece of code for a while now without making it work. Would be thankful if someone could give me a helping hand.

I have two pickers, picker1 and picker2, which have their Items and SelectedIndex properties logically connected to each other. A change in picker2 SelectedIndex causes an update of the Items and the SelectedIndex properties of the picker1 view. I have created a custom picker class which holds a bindable property for the items source  to make the view pickers Items properties update accordingly to the viewmodel.

```
class BindablePicker : Picker
{

    public static BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<BindablePicker, IEnumerable>(o => o.ItemsSource, default(IEnumerable), propertyChanged: OnItemsSourceChanged);
    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, IEnumerable oldvalue, IEnumerable newvalue)
    {
        var picker = bindable as BindablePicker;
        picker.Items.Clear();
        if (newvalue != null)
        {

            foreach (var item in newvalue)
            {
                picker.Items.Add(item.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The creation and binding of the view objects in the content page:

```
        BindablePicker Level1Picker = new BindablePicker { Title = "Select" };
        Level1Layout.Children.Add(Level1Picker);

        Level1Picker.SetBinding(BindablePicker.ItemsSourceProperty, "Level1Items");
        Level1Picker.SetBinding(BindablePicker.SelectedIndexProperty, "Level1Index");
```

BindablePicker Level2Picker = new BindablePicker { Title = "Select" };
            Level2Layout.Children.Add(Level2Picker);

```
        Level2Picker.SetBinding(BindablePicker.ItemsSourceProperty, "Level2Items");
        Level2Picker.SetBinding(BindablePicker.SelectedIndexProperty, "Level2Index");
```

and finally the view model:

```
class EducationLevelViewModel1 : BaseViewModel
{

    public EducationLevelViewModel1(Criterion educationLevel)
    {
        this.EducationLevel = educationLevel;
    }
    Criterion EducationLevel { get; set; }


    string level1Choice;
    string Level1Choice
    {
        get { return level1Choice ?? (EducationLevel._Filters[0]._RelevanceType.ToString()); }
        set { level1Choice = value; }
    }


    List<string> level1Items;
    public List<string> Level1Items
    {
        get { return level1Items ?? (level1Items = GetLevel1List()); }
        set
        {
            level1Items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    int level1Index = 0;

    public int Level1Index
    {
        get { return level1Index; }
        set
        {
            level1Index = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    void UpdateLevel1List()
    {
        Level1Choice = Level1Items[Level1Index];
        Level1Items = GetLevel1List();
        Level1Index =Level1Items.FindIndex(x => x == Level1Choice);

    }

    List<string> GetLevel1List()
    {

         if (Level2Items[(int)Level2Index] == Criterion.Filter.RelevanceType.Inadequacy.ToString())
             {
             return InadequacyItems;
         }
         else {
             return AllPickerItems;
         }

    }


    string level2Choice;
    public string Level2Choice
    {
        get { return level2Choice ?? (EducationLevel._Filters[1]._RelevanceType.ToString()); }
        set { level2Choice = value; }
    }

    List<string> level2Items;
    public List<string> Level2Items
    {
        get { return level2Items ?? (level2Items = GetLevel2List()); }
        set
        {
            level2Items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }




    int level2Index = 0;

    public int Level2Index
    {
        get { return level2Index; }
        set
        {
            level2Index = value;
            UpdateLevel1List();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    }
```

}
As you see, my viewmodel implements the BaseViewModel class which in turn implements the INotifyPropertyChanged. The logic in the vm is that a certain selectedindex in picker2 is triggering an update of the picker1 itemlist and selectedIndex. I'm doing this in the UpdateLevel1List(). Note the saving of the string selection so I can set the same selection of picker1 in the new list, otherwise I set it to index 0.

```
void UpdateLevel1List()
    {
        Level1Choice = Level1Items[Level1Index];
        Level1Items = GetLevel1List();
         Level1Index = Level1Items.FindIndex(x => x == Level1Choice) == -1 ? 0 : Level1Items.FindIndex(x => x == Level1Choice);

    }
```

The problem:
So the actual update of the picker1 itemlist updated in the view accordingly  the vm logic. But the new index is NOT, it is set to the default(-1). The app later crashes when i change the picker2 back to it's default selection.

I hope I made my self clear on what I'm trying to achieve here.